# Flutter Container Overlap when scrolling

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, containers

I have an UI as below(img1) and when I scroll the UI, the gradient cards will slightly overlapped its parent container but if I removed the gradient, everything works fine. Is there anyway to prevent this overlapped without removing the gradient background in my card?

Img1:

[image]

Img2:

[image]

The following is my sample code:

```
Container(
  margin: smallWidgetPadding,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      color: colorScheme.onPrimary,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              topRight: Radius.circular(30))),
      shadows: [BoxShadow(color: colorScheme.shadow, blurRadius: 5)]),
  child: Card(
      margin: margin,
      child: Container(
          decoration: ShapeDecoration(
              gradient: gradient, shape: roundedRectangleBorderless),
          child: child)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`clipBehavior`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container/clipBehavior.html) property of `Container` defaults to `Clip.none`. Set it to `Clip.antiAlias` on the outer `Container`.

```dart
Container(
  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
  // ...
)
```

Comment: Oh, I didnt thought of put it at the outer layer, thanks a lot...